# Calculating pascals triangle with large number of rows and parity

Tags: java, recursion

I'm using a simple recursive function to print out pascals triangles however the programs complexity seems to be exponential (might be wrong?) and I'm wanting to print a large number of rows of pascals triangle (50+ rows) and this doesn't seem possible with my current functions as it starts to choke at around 30+ rows.

I also wanted to calculate the parity of entries and print their parity instead of the numbers and I wasn't sure if I was missing something and didn't need to calculate the whole value of the entry to find it's parity and I could just use a rule?

```
public static long pascalsTriangle(int row, int col)
{
    if(row == 0 || col == 0 || col == row) return 1;
    else if(col == 1 || col == row-1) return row;
    else return pascalsTriangle(row - 1, col -1) + pascalsTriangle(row - 1, col);
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int num = 40;
    for(int row = 0; row <= num; row++)
    {
        for(int space = num; space > row; space--) System.out.printf("   ");
        for(int col = 0; col <= row; col++)
        {
            String str_n =   (pascalsTriangle(row, col) % 3 == 0)? "odd " : "even";
            System.out.printf("%6s", str_n);

        }
        System.out.println();
    } 
}
```

Comment: How does it *choke*?

Comment: I suppose the values are too large and my computer takes too long to calculate them. As I said I feel I'm missing something and I may not need to calculate the entries to find the parity.

Comment: Your ternary operator is incorrect. It should be `(pascalsTriangle(row, col) % 2 == 0)? "even" : "odd";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you calculate a value you are recalculating every parent required for that value, all the way back up to the root. The only data you need to calculate a row is the data from the previous row. Also, if you just want the parity then you only need to store the even/odd value for each row. So unless you really want to use recursion, I'd base my solution around the following:

```
  public static int[] calcNextRow(int[] prevRow) {
    int[] newRow = new int[prevRow.length + 1];
    newRow[0] = 1; 
    for (int i = 1; i < prevRow.length; ++i) {
      newRow[i] = (prevRow[i-1] + prevRow[i]) % 2; 
    }
    newRow[prevRow.length] = 1;
    return newRow;
  }
```

Then you can use that in a recursive manner, or just call it directly from a loop:

```
  public static void main() {
    int[] prevRow = { 1 };
    printRow(prevRow);

    for (int row = 0; row < 10; ++row) {
      int[] nextRow = calcNextRow(prevRow);
      printRow(nextRow);
      prevRow = nextRow;
    }
  }
```

If you want to calculate the actual values, then just remove the `% 2`:

```
  newRow[i] = prevRow[i-1] + prevRow[i];
```

Although you will obviously need to swap out `int` for `long` or `BigInteger` for larger trees.

Cheers,

Comment: This will overflow for the 40th row.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that you are doing a lot of redundant calculations. To calculate 40 choose 20, you calculate 39 choose 19 and 39 choose 20, which involves calculating 38 choose 19 twice. You calculate lower values many times to produce each output. Your code takes about n steps to produce a value of n, and the entries in the kth row of of Pascal's triangle add up to 2^k, so you are trying to do 2^40 ~ 10^12 steps.

Instead, you might store the values you have computed in a 2-dimensional array. This is called [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) or dynamic programming. To compute a choose b, this will take about (b+1)(a-b+1) steps, much faster than a choose b steps, but even most of these steps are saved when you compute several entries. To decrease the recursion depth, you might want to calculate the rows in order, from rows 0 through 40, even if you just want one value.

You might run into some overflow issues since the entries get large. Use [java.math.BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) variables instead of longs. This becomes necessary when you find entries get larger than 2^63 in the 67th and later rows.

To calculate the parity, you only need to keep track of the parity of earlier values.

There are much faster ways to calculate the entries of Pascal's triangle, and the parities. For example, a choose b is a!/(b!(a-b)!), which you can calculate better recursively along a row, (a choose 0 ) = 1, a choose b = (a choose min(b,a-b)), and (a choose b) = (a choose (b-1))*(a-b+1)/b. [There are even faster ways to determine the parities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem), but you should look at the pattern first.

Here is a Java memoized version of a choose b:

```
import java.math.*;
public static class Binomial
{
    private static BigInteger[][] memoized = new BigInteger[1001][1001];
    public static BigInteger comb(int n, int k)
    {
        if (k>n || n<0 || k<0)
            return BigInteger.valueOf(0);
        if (k > n-k)
            return comb(n,n-k);
        if (n>1000 || k>1000) // we could expand the memoized array dynamically
            return BigInteger.valueOf(-1);

        if (memoized[n][k] != null)
            return memoized[n][k];
        // we got here because we haven't computed it yet
        BigInteger result;
        if (n==0 && k==0)
            result = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        else 
            result= comb(n-1,k-1).add(comb(n-1,k));
        memoized[n][k] = result;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand there are more efficient ways however I am wondering If I need to calculate the entries at all? I was told that I don't and only need to find their parity, but I don't see how I can without the entry value unless I'm missing some rule.

Comment: You can keep just the last digit base 2. Even plus even is even. Even plus odd is odd. Etc. The advantage is that you can avoid using BigIntegers when you compute something like the parity of 600 choose 250. However, you need to fix the recursion, using something like memoization, or it will still take too many steps.

Comment: @joe: What was unsatisfactory about this answer? Should I delete it?

Comment: I didn't see your edit when I accepted the answer and Barney's solution was more what I was looking for. Keep your answer, it was useful.

Comment: @joe It's frustrating to take the trouble to explain the issues, to write out and test reusable code, and then have a later answer with less information and nonworking specialized code get accepted. But if that's what you want, I'll make sure not to answer any more of your questions.

Comment: I +1'd your solution and said you had a good answer, I just saw Barney's answer before your edit and it addressed all my concerns and provided an example. Not sure what response you were expecting but there was no need to down vote my question and be bitter about my decision..

Comment: @joe Selecting an answer that is less helpful, that includes code that does not work, makes the question with answers less informative for others who would find it later. So, when someone accepts the wrong answer I vote the question down.

Comment: I apologize if I selected the incorrect answer, I tested his code and adjusted mine (not using recursion) and was able to compute n rows (tried up to 100 rows) instantly, storing the values and comparing parity. Could you share what was wrong with his code?

Comment: Joe: you asked the question - the "correct" answer is the one **you** feel answers your question best - you do not need to apologise to anyone (including me, if you later decide Douglas' answer is better). Douglas:  I'm not sure on what basis you can judge what is "less helpful" or "the wrong answer" - those are both subjective calls, and can only be made by the OP. You can obviously vote how you like, but voting a question down because the OP accepted an answer other than yours is bad form, in my opinion.

Comment: @Barney: I didn't vote it down because the accepted answer was by someone else, but because the OP made the question less helpful to others by accepting a specialized and less complete answer that contains code that overflows when running the cases the OP's code could not handle. The FAQ says the OP should select what he believes is the best solution, not the first (or second, actually). This spotlight can help others, or not. Accepting your answer makes the question less clear to others, so I voted the question down. Joe complained about that, but as far as I can tell, it was appropriate.

Comment: @joe: As I stated, both of the other answers overflow before the 40th row when calculating Pascal's triangle. They would not overflow for the second question, when one reduces each coefficient mod 2 at each step.